# Understanding Bayes' theorem through an example

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, bayesian, bayes-theorem

Suppose I have three nodes A,B,C such that A and B are independent and pointed to C as the following:

> A --> C <-- B

Also Suppose that each node takes a peobability between (0,1) so that the sum of them will be 1 (for example, A=0.3, B=0.5, C=0.2).

My question is the following:

In this case, is it true that calculating `P(C|A,B)` is equivalent to calculating `P(C|A)*P(C|B)`? If not, what is the difference between both?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\Omega=\{1,2,3,\ldots,20\}$, with all $20$ outcomes equally probable, and

$$A= \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\quad \text{and} \quad B= \{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19\}.$$

Then $\Pr(A)=0.3$ and $\Pr(B)=0.5$ and $\Pr(A\ \&\ B) = \Pr(\{1,3,5\}) = 0.15 = 0.3\times0.5$, so $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Now suppose $C=\{2,4,17,19\}$.  Then

$$\Pr(C\mid A)\Pr(C\mid B) = \dfrac 1 3 \times \dfrac 1 5 = \dfrac 1 {15} = 0.666666\ldots\ne 0 = \Pr(C\mid A\ \&\ B).$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Well explained. May I ask you how did you come up with `1/3` and `1/5` in `Pr(C∣A)Pr(C∣B) = 1/3 * 1/5` ? If you don't mind to expand this last equation in a bit details. THANK YOU

Comment: $C\cap A = \{2,4\}$ and $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ so $1/3$ of the members of $A$ are members of $C$. And $C\cap B=\{17,10\}$, so $2$ of the $10$ members of $B$ are members of $C$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Oh yes that's right. I apologize for this silly question. I just now see the whole picture. It is basically a vann diagram in some sort. THANK YOU for your explanation.

Comment: Glad to help. ${}\qquad{}$